# Azure web service - change database connection string at runtime

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-sql-database, load-balancing, azure-web-app-service

The scenario is this:
An application wants to switch between databases, to avoid lengthy donwtimes when the database gets filled with new data.

So, the idea is to fill one database with data, then tell the web service (via a http call) to use *this* database from now on.

A couple of weeks/days later, we get new data. So we spend a couple of hours filling the other database and then tell the running web service to switch.

So, how would one go about this? The database connection string in the web service should survive a web service restart.

The whole thing runs on azure. Is there any place where the web service can store and modify settings?

Lots of Greetings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Web Apps have for this exact problem a dedicated solution.

Under the settings Section, there are Application settings. Application settings have Connections strings section. You can use this feature for your connection string handling in your application.

[image]

You can then change this connection string via Azure Web interface or via Azure Powershell.

An article how to use Azure connection string feature: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/.

Comment: Ok - so there is no easier way than powershell from within the controller action. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem @Volker, happy to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just have a couple connection strings in settings and program your application to switch between them as needed. As an option you can also have some common database where you store settings including connection string to your "data" database and again just program your app to do the switch.

Comment: Uh - same problem. How do I keep the information which one to use?

Comment: Ah - ok. And then some caching or so to reduce the roundtrip count. But I'm still hoping that the azure infrastucture offers a better way. :-)

Comment: It does, you are right. A dedicated functionality for the connection strings handling.

Answer (score 1):

The [recommended](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/) place to store connection strings for Azure Websites / Web Apps is as an Application Settings / Connection Strings!.

Internally these are stored as Environment Variables that are available at runtime.

This would be a reasonably trivial thing to push an update to, via Powershell, via REST from within the App itself, or another app. I'm not sure whether you would need to restart the web app to pick up the change.

For instance, you could have `ConnectionString1` and `ConnectionString2`. Then within your app you would be able to switch between the two at runtime (with `connectionstring = ConnectionString1`)

If you need to remember which one is current, you would need another data source, which could be anything, from a filesystem file! to an Azure Storage Table value, to another database. This would be a static database, that you wouldn't change, it would simply be there to store this configuration data for the site.

If you need to inject a new connection string you could do that via Powershell. There is also a REST API that you could use from within your app to manage that internally.

Comment: I don't mind to have 2 fixed ones there. I just need a way to remember which one to use, from within the application, in a way that survives a restart.

Comment: Give them a meaningful name and show which you're using! Parse part of the connection string that will tell you which you're using and display it somewhere.

Comment: I don't understand. I want to be able to switch, at runtime. So the web api has a .../.../switch-database endpoint. And the only way for the web service to do that is to execute a powershell script internally? I mean, in a normal .net application, settings are simply writable: string mysetting = App.Default.MySetting; App.Default.MySetting = "my new setting";

Comment: Thx! I'll see what's easier, the rest api or a third database.